# How do I troubleshoot the jfrog rt upload command?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have a local repo I created: `test_generic`

I'm trying to upload a local folder and I'm seeing this output:

`jfrog rt upload 'local-folder' 'test_generic/local-folder' --archive=zip --flat`

```
20:02:18 [Debug] JFrog CLI version: 2.45.0
20:02:18 [Debug] OS/Arch: linux/amd64
20:02:18 [Debug] Usage Report: Sending info...
20:02:18 [Debug] Saving build general details at: /tmp/jfrog/builds/b14a20bb9a7bb0b05fa940376fbc111e653308ec8b6234122b1b43719aa4d243/partials
20:02:18 [Debug] Sending HTTP GET request to: https://me.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/system/version
20:02:18 [Debug] Uploaded 0 artifacts.
20:02:18 [Debug] Creating temp build file at: /tmp/jfrog/builds/b14a20bb9a7bb0b05fa940376fbc111e653308ec8b6234122b1b43719aa4d243/partials
20:02:19 [Debug] Artifactory response: 200 
20:02:19 [Debug] JFrog Artifactory version is: 7.65.3
20:02:19 [Debug] Sending HTTP POST request to: https://me.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/system/usage
20:02:20 [Debug] Usage Report: Usage info sent successfully. Artifactory response: 200 
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

But I'm seeing `Uploaded 0 artifacts`.

This is infuriating. Even with debug turned on I'm provided with useless output.

How do I see what it's trying to do and why it did not upload artifacts?

Is it a problem with the folder? Is it a problem with the artifact path? Literally any feedback from the cli would be better than what I'm getting.

## Edit

Just want to make it clear I'm interested in understanding the verbosity/logging options I have available in the cli- not troubleshooting this specific problem.

Thus far I have found only `export JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=debug` which returns the output shown above which is not helpful or very verbose.

Just to add the `jf rt build-discard` command has this problem too. It tells me `Builds discarded.`, but no builds have been discarded. Again the command completes with no error and even with debug on I have no idea what it even *tried* to do.

Comment: You must specify your files of directory with "*" as ``jfrog rt upload 'local-folder/*' 'test_generic/local-folder' --archive=zip --flat``.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided CLI output, it appears that the artifact path might require some adjustment. When uploading a folder, it is important to correctly specify the path to the contents within it. For instance, using the format "`folder-name/*`" indicates that you intend to upload all the contents enclosed within the folder. Alternatively, you can directly navigate into the folder and utilize "`*`" as the parameter while performing the upload.

Here are a couple of examples to clarify the process:

1. If you wish to upload the contents of a folder while keeping the folder's name consistent with the local machine:

a. To achieve this, first navigate to the intended folder level and then execute the following command:

```
> jf rt upload "*" 'repository-name/local-folder/' --flat
```

This command will upload all files contained within the folder and store them under the "local-folder" within Artifactory.

b. In cases where you are one level above the folder, employing the subsequent command could prove helpful:

```
> jf rt upload "local-folder/*" 'repository-name/local-folder/' --flat
```

2. For uploading a folder as a zip archive to Artifactory, the following command is suitable:

   > jf rt upload 'local-folder/*' 'repository-name/local-folder.zip' --archive=zip --flat

This command will result in the upload of a zip file named "local-folder.zip" within Artifactory, encompassing all files originating from the "local-folder".

For more information on JFrog CLI command you can refer to the [CLI documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory).

Comment: While this was one of several syntax issues I was fighting with it doesn't answer my actual question. I suspect the answer is "the cli currently has no way of outputting _why_ it uploaded 0 artifacts", but I would like some confirmation that there is absolutely no trace or higher verbosity level that returns helpful information.

Comment: Yes, currently CLI does not have a log verbosity that returns the requested information but after the command is executed the CLI will create a log file in the end and complete information is present inside the log file.